# Can i forbid registering receiver in manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I'd like to send broadcast and receive it only if receiver registered in code with 
`registerReceiver()`, like `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` or `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. I'd like to forbid registering receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to send broadcast which can be received **ONLY** if broadcastReceiver is registered with `registerReceiver()`?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: - [Broadcast Receiver Register in Manifest vs. Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876015/broadcast-receiver-register-in-manifest-vs-activity) - [Is it better code practice to register a receiver in manifest or in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880741/is-it-better-code-practice-to-register-a-receiver-in-manifest-or-in-code)

Comment: could you clarify forbid registering receiver in manifest?

Comment: Thanks, but I saw these links, but unfortunately they didn't help me.

Comment: I mean the follows: i send broadcast from _application1_. I has _application2_ where broadcastReceiver registered in manifest and _application3_ where broadcastReceiver registered in code. I want's to receive broadcast in _application3_ and **NOT** in _application2_.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it by programatically also.

Please have a look into this registering a broadcast receiver programatically.

http://code4reference.com/2012/09/register-unregiste-broadcast-receiver-part/

Comment: The OP knows it's possible to do it both ways. That is not what he asked. Read the question more carefully.